# How to copy multiples files from server to usb drive

Tags: javascript, java, asp.net, html, activex

In my java web application need to copy 6 files from server to user machine usb drive on clicking of save files button.

If usb drive not found than need to show warning message 'no usb drive detected'.

I think, Due to  security issue it is not possible through Java script.

What will be the correct solution?

Comment: What have you tried so far? Do you have [mcve](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)?

Comment: You want to download files from a web server when they click a button, bypassing the browser's normal download procedure, then write the files directly to a media device on the user's computer... from a web browser? I'd take a guess that will be impossible, due to security concerns. Just download the files like normal and force the user to pick the save location.

Answer (score 1):

As a web site, you can't tell the user where he should save the files, on the other side, you can create a script that downloads the files in the place the script is. If you are on Windows:

1. Get the "wget for windows" binary and put it on the USB key.
2. Create a get_server_file.bat script file.
3. Edit the file and but commands lines like

   wget http://example.com/yourfile.txt

When the user clicks on the script, the files will be downloaded. If you need more options, look at the wget documentation.

Comment: Is it possible from ActiveX or Filesystemobject